# How to parse inside HTML tags with REBOL?

Tags: parsing, rebol

I have a web page that I've loaded with load/markup. I need to parse a bunch of stuff out of it, but some of the data is in the tags. Any ideas of how I can parse it? Here's a sample of what I've got (and tried) so far:

```
REBOL []

mess: {
<td>Bob Sockaway</td>
<td><a href=mailto:bsockaway@example.com>bsockaway@example.com</a></td>
<td>9999</td>
}

rules: [
    some [
        ; The expression below /will/ work, but is useless because of specificity.
        ; <td> <a href=mailto:bsockaway@example.com> s: string! </a> (print s/1) </td> | 

        ; The expression below will not work, because <a> doesn't match <a mailto=...>
        ; <td> <a> s: string! </a> (print s/1) </td> |

        <td> s: string! (print s/1) </td> |

        tag! | string! ; Catch any leftovers.
    ]
]
```

parse load/markup mess rules

This produces:

```
Bob Sockaway
9999
```

I would like to see something more like:

```
Bob Sockaway
bsockaway@example.com
9999
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Note! For what it's worth, I came up with a good simple ruleset that will get the desired results:

```
rules: [
    some [
        <td> any [tag!] s: string! (print s/1) any [tag!] </td> |
        tag! | string! ; Catch any leftovers.
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `mess` is processed with `LOAD/MARKUP` you get this (and I've formatted + commented with the types):

```
[
    ; string!
    "^/" 

    ; tag! string! tag!
    <td> "Bob Sockaway" </td>

    ; string!
    "^/"

    ; tag! tag!
    ;     string!
    ; tag! tag!
    <td> <a href=mailto:bsockaway@example.com>
        "bsockaway@example.com"
    </a> </td>

    ; (Note: you didn't put the anchor's href in quotes above...)

    ; string!
    "^/"

    ; tag! string! tag!
    <td> "9999" </td> 

    ; string!
    "^/"
]
```

Your output pattern matches series of the form `[<td> string! </td>]` but not things of the form `[<td> tag! string! tag! </td>]`.  Sidestepping the question posed in your title, you could solve this particular dilemma several ways.  One might be to maintain a count of whether you are inside a TD tag and print any strings when the count is non-zero:

```
rules: [
    (td-count: 0)
    some [
        ; if we see an open TD tag, increment a counter
        <td> (++ td-count)
        |
        ; if we see a close TD tag, decrement a counter
        </td> (-- td-count)
        |
        ; capture parse position in s if we find a string
        ; and if counter is > 0 then print the first element at
        ; the parse position (e.g. the string we just found) 
        s: string! (if td-count > 0 [print s/1])
        |
        ; if we find any non-TD tags, match them so the
        ; parser will continue along but don't run any code
        tag!
    ]
]
```

This produces the output you asked for:

```
Bob Sockaway
bsockaway@example.com
9999
```

But you also wanted to know, essentially, whether you can transition into string parsing from block parsing in the same set of rules (without jumping into open code).  I looked into it "mixed parsing" looks like it may be a feature addressed in Rebol 3.  Still, I couldn't get it to work in practice.  So I asked a question of my own.

[How to mix together string parsing and block parsing in the same rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392533/how-to-mix-together-string-parsing-and-block-parsing-in-the-same-rule)

Comment: I'm going to have to split this across two comments, because SO hates me...

Thanks your detailed answer! This is not exactly what I was after (my fault!), but it does solve the problem as stated. 

I was hoping to find out how to parse inside a tag! so I could get useful information from the various possible arguments to the tag. That is, if the tag! is `<a href="XXX">` it would be nice to be able to parse out the contents of the href string, instead of what's between the "a" tag.

Comment: Initializing the td-count inside the rules is a good trick and I had not thought of maintaining the state of the parse as you described. However, here is a more elegant formulation that doesn't require the extra variable:

`rules: [ some [ <td> any [tag!] s: string! (print s/1) any [tag!] </td> | tag! | string! ]]`

Sorry for the crap formatting. Apparently comments aren't first-class citizens... ; - )

Comment: Your parse rule will work and have certain semantics on nested tables, depends on what you want to happen in those cases.  In any case, I've udpated with a link to a question I asked to try and follow up on the issue you brought up in the title...

Comment: @HostileFork I tried to use count , rules parsing is true but nothing is inserted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987905/rebol-red-parse-html-rules-returns-true-but-nothing-is-inserted

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a pretty good solution.  It may have to be generalized if you had lots of different tags whose attributes you need.

I was looking for the id attribute of the query tag!:

```
<query id="5">
```

In the parse rule for tag!, I did this:

```
  | set t tag! (
    p: make block! t 
    if p/1 = 'query [_qid: to-integer p/3]
  )
```

More tags to look at, I'd use case.  And maybe this would be better to set _qid

```
to-integer select p 'id=
```

I ended up needing to parse another tag and this is a nice general pattern

```
switch p/1 [
  field [_fid: to-integer p/id= _field_type: p/field_type=]
  query [_qid: to-integer p/id=]
]
```

Comment: that doesn't work as a general rule, you should avoid weird tags such as comments

Comment: proof of concept: 
 
aa: load/markup {
<!--
 var loading_text = 'loading, wait';
// -->
}
parse aa [some [set t tag! (p: make block! t switch p/1 [ !-- [print select p '=]]) | string!] ]