# Conditional "marking" in Rebol / Red parse

Tags: rebol, red

Subsequent to [Rebol / Red Parse html rules returns true but nothing is inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987905/rebol-red-parse-html-rules-returns-true-but-nothing-is-inserted)

How to mark the end of the fist main div only (when div-count is 0 first time), not the second one, or is there a way to break out of parse conditionally to a variable value ?

```
        content: {<div class="main">
          <h1>
            Big TITLE
          </h1>
          <div>
            <section>
              <p>a paragraph</p>
            </section>
             <section>
              <p>a paragraph</p>
            </section>
              <section>
              <p>a paragraph</p>
            </section>
           </div>
           <div>
              <p>Blah Blah</p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          Another Div
        </div>

    <div class="main">
          <h1>
            Big TITLE
          </h1>
          <div>
            <section>
              <p>a paragraph</p>
            </section>
             <section>
              <p>a paragraph</p>
            </section>
              <section>
              <p>a paragraph</p>
            </section>
           </div>
           <div>
              <p>Blah Blah</p>
           </div>

        </div>
        <div>
          Another Div
        </div>    
        }

        rules: [
             thru <div class="main">
             (div-count: 1)
              some [
                "<div" (probe ++ div-count) skip
              |
                "</div>" mark:  ( probe -- div-count   if div-count = 0 [insert mark "closing main div"]) skip 
              |  skip
             ]
          ]
        parse/all content rules
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you need a mix of `opt` and `if` keywords. Consider a simplified example:

```
count: 0
div: ['div some integer! /div]

probe parse [
    div 1 2 3 /div 
    div 4 5 6 /div
    div 7 8 9 /div
][
    some [
        div (count: count + 1) opt [if (count = 1) mark:]
    ] 
]

probe mark
```

Here, after each `div` rule match, increment of a counter happens. After that there's an optional match -- if counter is at `1`, then current input position is marked, otherwise parsing continues as-is. Because this rule is optional, parsing will continue despite its success or failure.

Additionally, if you want to break out of a parsing loop (that is, `some`, `any` or `while`), you can use `break` (returns success) or `reject` (returns failure), again in combination with `opt`, `if` and conditional `paren!` expression.

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution working in Red and Rebol using your approach plus adding some  selfmodification to the rules

```
rules: [
    thru <div class="main">
    (div-count: 1 clear rules/5/8 )
    some [
        "<div" (probe div-count: div-count + 1) skip
        |
        "</div>" mark:  ( 
             probe div-count: div-count - 1   
             if div-count = 0 [
                 insert mark "closing main div"  append rules/5/8 [to end]  
             ]
         ) [] skip 
         |  skip
     ]
 ]
```

Comment: hi thanks but I don't understand what clear rules/5/8 is supposed to do ?

Comment: Clearing this part of the rule (the emtpty block in the original rule) makes the rule reuseable by generating the initial rule again, if you want to use the rule more than once in a program or function.